# Implode 1 index of an array with 2 indices

Tags: php, arrays, implode

I have an array $skills. I want to make a comma seperated list of all the `skills`.

I thought I could do this with array implode, but it looks like I'll have to use a foreach() and append to a string. Is there a way to do this with just array implode?

```
[skills] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [email] => don.pinkus@gmail.com
                    [skill] => Statistics
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [email] => don.pinkus@gmail.com
                    [skill] => Adobe Creative Suite
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [email] => don.pinkus@gmail.com
                    [skill] => HTML + CSS
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [email] => don.pinkus@gmail.com
                    [skill] => Web Analytics
                )
```

Comment: Why does skills have an email attached to each skill especially since it's all the same email?

Comment: used elsewhere in the code, dont want to reload the array or have two arrays

Answer (score 3):

how about:

```
implode(",", array_column($skills, 'skill'));
```

Answer (score 0):

For PHP 5.5, you can use Lyn's solution. For versions before that (5.3 and 5.4):

```
implode(', ', array_map(function($a) {return $a['skill'];}, $skills));
```

Breaking it down into multiple lines to make it a little easier to read:

```
$array = array_map(
    function($a) {
        return $a['skill'];
    }, $skills);
echo implode(', ', $array);
```

Here's a solution for before PHP 5.3 (and probably the most efficient):

```
$out = '';
foreach ($skills as $val){
    $out .= $val['skill'].', ';
}
echo rtrim($out, ', ');
```